# How to download large sized Files (size > 50MB) in java

Tags: java, download, p2

I'm downloading files from a remote location, and the download is complete for smaller sized files and in-complete for large sized files (>10 MB). Here is my code that i have used for downloading files from remote server .

```
    File dstFile = null;
    // check the directory for existence.
    String dstFolder = LOCAL_FILE.substring(0,LOCAL_FILE.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
    if(!(dstFolder.endsWith(File.separator) || dstFolder.endsWith("/")))
        dstFolder += File.separator;

    // Creates the destination folder if doesn't not exists
    dstFile = new File(dstFolder);
    if (!dstFile.exists()) {
        dstFile.mkdirs();
    }
    try {
        URL url = new URL(URL_LOCATION);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76"); 
        //URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        int available = stream.available();
        byte b[]= new byte[available];
        stream.read(b);
        File file = new File(LOCAL_FILE);
        OutputStream out  = new FileOutputStream(file);
        out.write(b);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        VeBLogger.getInstance().log( e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Any other API exists for downloading Huge Files ?

Comment: What is your actual question or what is not working about this code?

Comment: Call `flush()` on your `FileOutputStream` and then `close()` it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [apache commons IO library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi).
It's easy. I have used it in many projects.

```
File dstFile = null;
// check the directory for existence.
String dstFolder = LOCAL_FILE.substring(0,LOCAL_FILE.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
if(!(dstFolder.endsWith(File.separator) || dstFolder.endsWith("/")))
    dstFolder += File.separator;

// Creates the destination folder if doesn't not exists
dstFile = new File(dstFolder);
if (!dstFile.exists()) {
    dstFile.mkdirs();
}
try {
    URL url = new URL(URL_LOCATION);
    FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, dstFile);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e);
    VeBLogger.getInstance().log( e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Amit : Thanks for your reply.. Any restriction in terms of file size is there while using  FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, dstFile), Can we download all files (regardless of its size) ?

Comment: do we need to take care of closing the stream when invoking the 
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, dstFile) method ?

Comment: No need, see the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.2/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java#FileUtils.copyURLToFile%28java.net.URL%2Cjava.io.File%29), And there is no limit in size

Comment: HiberKnight: Hi, whether this copyURLToFile() copies the list of files present in a directory from server ? i mean that if a directory in server has a list of files and if i provide the the directory location as the URL argument. then whether it holds good ?

Comment: I think it is not possible to download all the files from server.
Is there any API which does this ?

Comment: No, It is not. For that you need to download the directory page prase all the anchor tags, get the url for individual files and then download them in loop.

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to be a costlier operation (getting the HTML file and parsing all the tags). Any other way (or open source API) exists for accomplishing this ?

Comment: because everywhere in blogs, they are talking about file download only and not directory download.

Comment: HiberKnight: How to get the URL for individual files in a directory ?

Comment: You don't need to create the folders leading up to the target folder. From the docs: `Copies bytes from the URL source to a file destination. The directories up to destination will be created if they don't already exist. destination will be overwritten if it already exists.
Warning: this method does not set a connection or read timeout and thus might block forever. Use copyURLToFile(URL, File, int, int) with reasonable timeouts to prevent this.`

Answer (score 3):

Firstly,
I'd suggest you use:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
```

instead of:

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
```

(To avoid building up memory usage)

```
try
{
    FileInputStream fileInputStream  = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] buf=new byte[8192];
    int bytesread = 0, bytesBuffered = 0;
    while( (bytesread = fileInputStream.read( buf )) > -1 ) {
        out.write( buf, 0, bytesread );
        bytesBuffered += bytesread;
        if (bytesBuffered > 1024 * 1024) { //flush after 1MB
            bytesBuffered = 0;
            out.flush();
        }
    }
}
finally {
    if (out != null) {
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems strange to avoid BufferedInputStream when you are implementing exactly a buffer here. Can you elaborate why BufferedInputStream is not a good fit?

Comment: The question is asking how to download a file from a URL. FileInputStream is not how you read/download a file from a URL. FileInputStream is used to read data from the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Please read BufferedInputStream's method .available() in the API.

It returns the number of available bytes already downloaded (ie. the number of bytes you can read out of the stream without accessing/waiting for the network).

You should create a fixed size byte array, fx. 2048 bytes, and use the read() methods until it returns -1.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String DownloadFile(String path, String outputFileName) {    
        try {
            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(path).cookie()
                .maxBodySize(0)
                .ignoreContentType(true)
                .execute();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFileName));
            out.write(response.bodyAsBytes());
            out.close();
            return outputFileName;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: i use Jsoup library. you can consult