# How to read url with ~300 MB of json text

Tags: java, json, curl, url, httpsurlconnection

I'm trying to read the text from https://mtgjson.com/api/v5/AllPrintings.json. I have tried with this code:

```
url = new URL("https://mtgjson.com/api/v5/AllPrintings.json");
conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())); // error here

String inputLine;
StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    content.append(inputLine);
}
System.out.println(content);
```

I keep getting IOException with the BufferedReader (conn.getInputStream()). The text from the url does not contain a new line character. How can I read this data?

(Edit)
I'm using Java 1.8 with Apache NetBeans 16. I'm sticking with 1.8 so I can also use Eclipse Neon3.

Error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://mtgjson.com/api/v5/AllPrintings.json
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
    at tests.MtgJson.main(MtgJson.java:44)
```

I've also been trying ProcessBuilder with curl and it's giving better results but curl stops after about a minute. Curl continues if I terminate the program inside Netbeans but doesn't always finish creating the file contents. I shouldn't have to stop my program for curl to continue. Is there something I'm missing for curl to work?

```
String command = "curl --keepalive-time 5 https://mtgjson.com/api/v5/AllPrintings.json";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command.split(" "));
pb.redirectOutput(new File("AllPrintings.json"));
Process process = pb.start();
// use while() or process.waitfor();
while(process.isAlive())
    Thread.sleep(1000);
process.destroy();
```

Answer (since I can't post one):

```
String command = "curl https://mtgjson.com/api/v5/AllPrintings.json";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command.split(" "));

pb.inheritIO(); // keep the program from hanging
pb.redirectOutput(new File("AllPrintings.json"));

Process process = pb.start();
process.waitFor(); // waiting for the process to terminate.
```

The complete file is created without hanging then the program will close. Curl outputs info to the console and must be consumed [(found here)](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjava/comments/i6zfj3/comment/g0z0wbq/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Comment: What do you want to do with that huge lump of data? Just print it to the screen? You probably can't load it into memory as a whole as long as you don't modify the JVM settings for heap size, but depending on your needs, maybe you don't need to...

Comment: To start with, don't use a line-oriented method when there are no lines in the input.  You can just use read() on the InputStream, in convenient buffer-loads.  I'd also try and avoid building the entire 300M-char string (=600M bytes as UTF-16).

Comment: @cyberbrain I want to save it as a file then parse the file for an offline database. I would like to get my application to do this so the user doesn't have to download it themselves. I already have a way to parse the file so I need a way to get the file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25045224/21197077 this might be helpful

Comment: FYI: you're not doing yourself many favors by staying on a  9 year old Java version that has reached its EOL last year in order to stay on an IDE release version from 7 years ago. Eclipse is free and JDK installations are free. Get the latest Eclipse and a recent JDK.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use byte->character conversion with `BufferedReader` just to make a copy. Instead copy the content directly to a file using Java NIO [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)), and then use the output file for any further processing:

```
Path file = Path.of("big.json"); 
// Older JDK use Paths.get("filename")
Files.copy(conn.getInputStream(), file);
System.out.println("Saved "+Files.size(file)+" bytes to "+file);
```

Which should print:

```
Saved 313144388 bytes to big.json
```

Comment: Sorry, I should of said the version of java I'm using so I will edit my question (Java 1.8 with Apache NetBeans 16). `of()` isn't a method I can use. I was probably too focused on trying to keep it short. Though I can use `Paths.get(URI)` or `Paths.get(String, String...)`. Unfortunately I am still getting an IOException with `Files.copy()`. The similarity between the errors is `conn.getInputStream()`.

Comment: It's a http 403 response. Not sure why I would get that if I can view the data in a browser.

Comment: Add the exception details to the question.

Comment: Note that I've run above code on JDK19.